# Remove "Using filesort" for simple MySQL query

Tags: mysql, performance, filesort

I am trying to remove filesort from a simple MySQL query.

The table has the column `active` which is either 0 or 1 and has a column `season_average` which is an integer, and no joins.

My select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM `group` WHERE active=1 
ORDER BY season_average DESC
```

I have tried an index on `active`, on `season_average`, and multiple columns on `(active, season_average)` and `(season_average, active)` None of which solve the issue.

This SQL Fiddle shows the problem I am having: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77861/2

Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: You cannot judge performance of a query upon small dataset. Populate your table with plenty of data then execute this query.

Comment: I've run the query on 92 records and got the following result:
`id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE group ref active_seasonAverage active_seasonAverage 1 const 44 Using where`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subrata Dey Pappu had the right idea by saying that judging query performance with a small sample set is bad testing to see query performance. In your case, the query optimizer determined that it was easier to do a full table scan of 5 rows and sort the order by using a [quicksort](https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/) than to use the composite index `(active, season_average)` that you had created.  This is evident by running the explain plan:
 [image]
which shows the possible key choices as `active_seasonAverage`, however no `key` is used for that small of a sample set of data.

While growing your sample set size will adjust how the data is accessed by the query optimizer (as indicated by Subrata Dey Pappu in the comments above), you can trick it (this is not recommended to hardcode into your application) by running the same query but like so:

```
 SELECT 
*
FROM `group` force index (active_seasonAverage) WHERE active=1 
ORDER BY season_average DESC
```

Which forces the query optimizer to use your composite key and the explain plan will look something like this:

[image]

Notice that the `key` is not `NULL`, instead it is using `active_seasonAverage` and under `Extra` there is no `Using filesort`.

---

Also, with small dataset testing, consider the following excerpt from the Mysql Manual page [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables
>   where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query
>   needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than
>   working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even
>   if not all the rows are needed for the query.

As such, perform your testing with various indexes in place with realistic and large sets of data, running your tests thru [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply

Comment: But, did it actually speed up the query?  "Removing filesort" does not always speed up a query.

Comment: Are you curious if that was the case Rick? cause OP question was "how to remove filesort for simple query"...not if removing the filesort makes the query faster...